# Ember-CLI on Apache TOMCAT

Tags: tomcat, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to load my ember-cli inbuilt server application on Apache tomcat.

I built my application in production mode using

> ember build --environment production

I moved the files in my **/dist** folder to my apache tomcat **/webapps** folder started my apache server but when i go to the **URL: "localhost:8081/index.html"**

The page is blank although the it works perfect with the inbuilt server. 
Using Ember inspector i can see the routes that are defined but not able to view any output.

I followed this guide **[http://thetechcofounder.com/getting-started-with-ember-js-using-ember-cli/#*=*](http://thetechcofounder.com/getting-started-with-ember-js-using-ember-cli/#_=_)**
to create my ember-cli application any help would be great.

Comment: i have the same problem, you could find the answer on [Embli-Cli Not work after Building](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835599/embli-cli-not-work-after-building)

Answer (score 5):

1. Inside `config/environment.js` file, there is a property called `locationType`. Set its value to `hash`

[image]

2. Also, manually moving files from your `/dist` folder is not cool. ;) Instead, you can specify an `output-path` property in your `.ember-cli` with the location inside `webapps` you are trying to move the files to.

[image]