# Embli-Cli Not work after Building

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Iam working around Ember-Cli.I build a project and customize the "ember-cli-build.js" but finally it doesn't work.
this is my work steps:
1) `ember new myapp 
cd myapp
ember server`
it works fine and i can see my project on "http://localhost:4200" 
2) then run `ember build --environment=production`  and get  `Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/".` so it appear that my project built. 
3) then i run this url on browser that direct to my dist directory project

```
localhost/~/myapp/dist/index.html
```

but nothing shows.
i check the console and it seems that the "ember" is running, but nothing shows on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the anwser. first of all on the "enviroment" change these 
 `locationType: 'hash'`

```
APP: {
  rootElement: "#page-base"
}
```

and then go to "project/app/index.html" and place `<div id="page-base"></div>`

then build the project by `ember build --environment=production`

it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that you deploy everything inside `/dist` folder to your server and it will be the root of your http server. And there is a way to simulate this behavior on your local environment. All you need is to install [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) globally in your system:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

then navigate to the `dist` folder of your app:

```
cd myapp/dist
```

and start the http-server:

```
http-server -o
```

That's it. You have your built ember application running in your browser locally.